# haben oder sein mit dem Verb "enden" im Perfekt

Tags: perfect-tense

> Ich **bin** bestimmt so geendet, weil ich mich von meiner Familie abgesetzt habe.

Ich bin diesem Satz begegnet und es verwirrt mich, warum das Hilfsverb sein nicht haben benutzt wird. Ich habe es im Woerterbuch nachgeschagen, aber eine richtige Antwort finde ich nicht.

Bitte helft mir.

Answer (score 3):

1. Die einfache Antwort: Weil das Verb *enden* in gewissen Bedeutungen das Perfekt mit *sein* bilden kann (alternativ zu *haben*), wie man zum Beispiel [dem Duden entnehmen kann](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/enden). Den hier vorliegenden Gebrauch in einem der Dudeneinträge wiederzufinden, ist eventuell nicht ganz einfach. Es handelt sich um die Bedeutung „zeitlich aufhören, zu Ende sein; zu Ende gehen, ausgehen“, gemeint ist ein vorläufiges Ende, der derzeitige Zustand wird als Sackgasse empfunden.
2. Natürlich hat die Duden-Redaktion das nicht ausgewürfelt. Der Hintergrund ist folgender: Verben, die eine nicht aktiv herbeigeführte Änderung des eigenen Zustands (des Subjekts) beschreiben, bilden das Perfekt mit *sein*. Das Verb *enden* kann hier so verstanden werden, daß es eine Zustandsänderung beschreibt: Ich war einmal anders, aber jetzt bin ich so und so geendet. Im Grunde könnte hier ja genausogut *werden* stehen: „Ich bin bestimmt so geworden …“ Und *werden* ist natürlich das Verb der Zustandsänderung schlechthin und bildet das Perfekt immer mit *sein*.

Answer (score 1):

Die Alternative wäre:

> Ich **habe** bestimmt so geendet, weil ich mich von meiner Familie abgesetzt habe.

Das würde aber bedeuten, dass ein von mir ausgeführter Vorgang (z.B. Schreiben eines Buches) ein bestimmtes Ende genommen hat, denn der Satz sagt aus, dass ich etwas gemacht habe das ein Ende hat. Das ist aber nicht gemeint.

Der Satz lautet ganz korrekt:

> Ich **bin** bestimmt so geendet, weil ich mich von meiner Familie abgesetzt habe.

Das heißt, dass etwas mit mir passiert ist, und das hat dazu geführt, dass ich mich *am Ende* (also jetzt) genau in dem Zustand befinde, in dem ich nun mal **bin.**

---

Ergänzung
Es betrifft zwar nicht das Verb *enden,* aber es ist auch zu bedenken, dass es Verben gibt, für die es regionale Unterschiede gibt. Die Verben, die die Lage einer Person beschreiben (stehen, liegen, sitzen usw.) werden in den meisten Gebieten des deutschen Sprachraums mit dem Hilfsverb *haben* gebildet (*»Ich habe im Bett gelegen«*). In Österreich, der Schweiz und in südlichen Gebieten Deutschlands wird aber das Hilfsverb *sein* verwendet (*»Ich bin im Bett gelegen«*). In Deutschland gilt das Hilfsverb *sein* bei diesen Verben das als nicht-standardsprachlich. (Wenn das bayrische Schüler im Aufsatz so schreiben wird das als Fehler gewertet.) In Österreich und der Schweiz wird das aber an Schulen genau so unterrichtet. Das ist dort also korrektes Hochdeutsch.